# Unable to click image button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to click an image button, but i am getting  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException. I even Checked if the element is present in any iframe by iterating through the frames. It is not present in any of the frames. Am i missing something?. Can someone please help me out with this.

Below is the code i am trying:

```
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);  
WebElement image = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//tr//table[@title='User Prompt Input']//div[@id='IconImg_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_3']")));  
actions.click(image).build().perform();
```

Exception i am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 45 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //tr//table[@title='User Prompt Input']//div[@id='IconImg_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_3']
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'W1856237', ip: '192.168.43.137', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
    at com.ExpTestcases.TestOne.main(TestOne.java:105)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tr//table[@title='User Prompt Input']//div[@id='IconImg_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_3']"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
```

And this is the html code for the image button:

```
<table role="button" aria-label="User Prompt Input" aria-pressed="false" title="User Prompt Input" style="display: block; cursor: pointer;" false"="" margin:0px"="" id="vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_3" class="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" aria-labelledby="ariaLabelledBy_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_3" tabindex="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr valign="middle">
                <td id="iconleft_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_3" class="">
                    <div style="width:2px;height:35px"></div>
                </td>
                <td id="iconmid_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_3" align="center" style="height:35px;" class="">
                    <div style="overflow:hidden;height:31px;" valign="middle">
                    <div id="IconImg_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_3" class="imo" style="width:31px;height:31px;background-image:url('images/main/vertbar_icons.png');background-position:-1px -127px;margin-top:2px;cursor:pointer"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id="iconright_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_3" class="">
                    <div style="width:2px;height:35px"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Xpath trials:

- //table[@aria-label="User Prompt Input"]
- //tr//table[@title='User Prompt Input']//div[@id='IconImg_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_3']
- //table[@aria-label="User Prompt Input"]/@title
- //tr//table[@aria-label="User Prompt Input"]/@title

Comment: if running it only in [selenium ide](https://a9t9.com/kantu/) (and not web driver) is ok, you can use kantu's visual [xclick (_image of button_)](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/xclick) command and avoid debugging the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to invoke `click()` on the element so instead of using `visibilityOfElementLocated()` method you need to use **`elementToBeClickable()`** method and can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("table[id^='vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_'][aria-label='User Prompt Input'] div.imo[id^='IconImg_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_'][style*='vertbar_icons']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//table[starts-with(@id,'vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_') and @aria-label='User Prompt Input']//div[@class='imo' and starts-with(@id,'IconImg_vertBar_leftPaneW_icon_')][contains(@style,'vertbar_icons')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thank you are your inputs. i tried with the approach suggested by you, but its still not able to locate the element.